# Command and Conquer 3: Kane's Wrath does not start

Tags: origin, command-and-conquer-3-tiberium-wars, command-and-conquer-kanes-wrath

I want to play C&C:KW but the game simply does not start.

I have read a couple of forums and it seems there are a lot of problems with the game on windows 8.

My Specifications:

- Window 8.1
- Lenovo S540
- i5-4210U
- 8 GB RAM
- 250 GB SSD
- Intel HD graphics
- AMD Radeon HD 8670M

This is what happens when I try to run the game:
[image]

What I already tried:

1. turn off Origin in game
2. Installing older DirectX version
3. Run the game in Windows Vista, 7 and xp compatibility mode
4. Use start parameters: `-xres 1080 -yres 1920`

All with no success

Comment: You could try some other compatibility modes?

Comment: I tried Windows xp

Comment: A couple of threads about this issue on answers.ea.com showed it could be due to a recent update to the Intel HD Graphics drivers... Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Apparently, on NVidia, there's a 'preferred graphics processor' setting to change to "high-performance" that apparently makes sure it doesn't use the intel HD GPU but the video card's. Maybe you should find some similar setting for your AMD card?

Comment: I have not found any option to force use my AMD Radeon. I've looked for this for a time and found no way to do it. BTW the AMD Radeon card sucks next time I buy a laptop with an NVidia card.

Comment: Another suggestion I found was to _downgrade_ the Intel HD drivers to a version from before the problem.